# pactl load-module module-loopback too loud

Tags: sound

So, I wanted to record Five Nights At Freddy's and then when I played the video, my voice was way louder then the game and literally you cant hear the game sound effects, mostly my voice. I don't know how it happened, I accidentally left pactl load-module module-loopback on, then I called a friend on skype and it got louder and I don't know how to reduce it.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Your question would be clearer if you were to add details like what you tried to fix it and what happened when you did. I can only hope my answer is helpful as the information you've provided is a bit limited. In future please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask You are likely to get usable answers a lot faster if you follow those guidelines. I thank you and the community thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

Try PulseAudio Volume Control. you can install it from the software center or from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

This program allows setting both input and output levels for streams, applications, and devices and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: My right telepathy antenna has broken off and the OP was too far away from me to link directly to his computer.  Luckily both of yours still work! ;-)

Comment: @Fabby Whether they are working or not remains to be seen. I certainly hope so! ;-)